# What is the best solution to create a function that returns draw?

Tags: python, panel

I have a classic UI panel, and I'd like to call a drawing function that always draws the same thing, and I was thinking of using a function.
Actually I don't even know how to correctly ask this question, I hope you correct me.

Basically I would like to call a layout data block to insert where I need it, something like this:

```
class MY_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):

    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_idname = "My Panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "My Panel"

    def draw(self, context):

        #scn.scn_prop.my_bool_one / my_bool_two property is declared in a PropertyGroup

        scn=context.scene

        layout = self.layout    
        layout.prop(scn.scn_prop, 'my_bool_one', text='Show menu 1')
        if scn.scn_prop.my_bool_one:
            layout.label(text='Menu 1')
            layout.label(text='Many options from menu 1')
            ##Avoid to repeat this:
            layout.label(text='My mini-menu')
            layout.label(text='This is just an example')
            layout.prop(scn.scn_prop,'my_bool_three',text='Do something')

        layout.prop(scn.scn_prop, 'my_bool_two', text='Show menu 2')

        if scn.scn_prop.my_bool_two:
            layout.label(text='Menu 2')
            layout.label(text='Many options from menu 2')
            ##Avoid to repeat this:
            layout.label(text='My mini-menu')
            layout.label(text='This is just an example')
            layout.prop(scn.scn_prop,'my_bool_three',text='Do something')
```

So here's the problem, my "Mini-menu" is actually something complex, I wish I could call it without having to rewrite it all the time. I don't know which way to go. I think it can be solved with a function within the class, but I have many doubts about it

Comment: Hi. So what are your 'doubts' about it? Did you try it and it didn't work?

Comment: It works like this, but it is only the example where I would like to understand how not to have to repeat the "Mini-menu" every time, if I can insert this "Mini-menu" in a function, so as to insert only one call to the function that draw the "Mini-menu"

Comment: I meant did you try the function? Surely very easy to test?

Comment: I doubt if I have explained myself wrong. I wish the "Mini-menu" was part of a function to be called, in order not to have to rewrite under each menu 1 and menu 2 every time, but I don't know how to build this function, and where to put it.

Comment: The panel is just a class right? So you can easily add a method and pass the scene or context: `def my_drw(self, context)`. Consider to use a for loop in order to draw the properties in one go (if there are 2+ bools).